# What does the "pseudo-register number" argument to windbg StopOnException do?

Tags: windbg

Here's the help text for the windbg command `StopOnException` (aka `soe` for short):

```
0:000> !soe
usage: StopOnException [-derived] [-create | -create2] <type name>
                       [<pseudo-register number for result>]
ex:    StopOnException -create System.OutOfMemoryException 1
```

What is the argument "**pseudo-register number for result**" for? The example uses the value `1` but without any follow up.

The only other [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/sos-dll-sos-debugging-extension#commands) I can finds says just this:

> ```
> StopOnException [-derived] [-create | -create2] <Exception> <Pseudo-register number>
> ```
>
> Causes the debugger to stop when the specified exception is thrown,
> but to continue running when other exceptions are thrown.
>
> The -derived option catches the specified exception and every
> exception that derives from the specified exception.

...no mention of this argument at all in the text. Nor any other use of the word "pseudo" on that page, or "register" with the same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

There is additional help text within windbg that does explain it. Took me a while to realize this, maybe it will be useful to others new to windbg:

```
 0:000> !help stoponexception
```

produces:

> ```
>  !StopOnException [-derived] 
>                   [-create | -create2] 
>                   <Exception> 
>                   [<Pseudo-register number>]
> ```
>
> !StopOnException helps when you want the Windows Debugger to stop on a
> particular managed exception, say a System.OutOfMemoryException, but
> continue running if other exceptions are thrown. The command can be
> used in two ways:
>
> 1. When you just want to stop on one particular CLR exception
>
>    At the debugger prompt, anytime after loading SOS, type:
>
>    !StopOnException -create System.OutOfMemoryException 1
>
>    **The pseudo-register number (1) indicates that SOS can use register
>    $t1 for    maintaining the breakpoint**. The -create parameter allows
>    SOS to go ahead    and set up the breakpoint as a first-chance
>    exception. -create2 would set    it up as a 2nd-chance exception.
> 2. When you need more complex logic for stopping on a CLR exception
>
>    !StopOnException can be used purely as a predicate in a larger
>    expression.    If you type:
>
>    !StopOnException System.OutOfMemoryException 3
>
>    then **register** $t3 will be set to 1 if the last thrown exception on
>    the     current thread is a System.OutOfMemoryException. Otherwise,
>    $t3 will be set    to 0. Using the Windows Debugger scripting
>    language, you could chain     such calls together to stop on various
>    exception types. You'll have to     manually create such predicates,
>    for example:
>
>    sxe -c "!soe System.OutOfMemoryException 3;
>    !soe -derived System.IOException 4;
>    .if(@$t3==1 || @$t4==1) { .echo 'stop' } .else {g}"
>
> The -derived option will cause StopOnException to set the
> **pseudo-register** to 1 even if the thrown exception type doesn't exactly
> match the exception type given, but merely derives from it. So,
> "-derived System.Exception" would catch every exception in the
> System.Exception heirarchy.
>
> The **pseudo-register number** is optional. If you don't pass a number,
> SOS will  use **pseudo-register** $t1.

I highlighted the relevant portions.

Essentially, this option allows you to specify which pseudo-register should be used to keep track of the breakpoint. Perhaps in some cases if you don't want to overwrite an existing important value, specifying your own register selection can avoid that.

More info on pseuo-register values: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/pseudo-register-syntax